# Unable to enable PHP LDAP even though I have edited php.ini and php_ldap.dll is in the right place?

Tags: php, apache, ldap, wamp

I've been working with a WAMP install for quite a while now with LDAP enabled and everything is going smoothly. Now though I have to set up another machine and for some reason I can't enable LDAP.

I checked the output of `phpinfo()` and the LDAP section isn't there. I edited `php.ini` to uncomment the line:

```
extension = php_ldap.dll
```

I also checked the filepath being searched for extensions and the file `php_ldap.dll` is in the right place.

I'm *positive* I'm editing the right `php.ini` file since I checked the filepath being shown by `phpinfo()`, and also I am able to successfully enable/disable other extensions.

I have rebooted Apache after every change made.

While Googling this, the only solutions I found were those above, plus one or two mentions of editing the Windows `PATH` variable to include the path to `php.ini`? Tried it even though it didn't make sense to me (as I already know `php.ini` is being parsed). I also checked my previous install on the other machine and from what I can see I never added any PHP directories to the `PATH` on that machine

#### Edit with complete answer

Frank's answer below led me to the solution so I thought I'd consolidate everything now.

To Enable LDAP Support on a WAMP server:

1. Uncomment `extension = php_ldap.dll` in `php.ini`
2. **IMPORTANT**: Make sure that you're editing the right `php.ini` by checking the output of `phpinfo()`
3. Check the `php.ini` file for the location of your extensions directory
4. Check that `php_ldap.dll` is located in that directory
5. (**THE STEP I MISSED**) Find the files `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` and add their directory to the Windows PATH
6. Reboot Apache. If LDAP is enabled there will be a section about it in the output of `phpinfo()`

Comment: There are a few hints here: http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php .  Note you need to add two other DLLs `libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll`.  You may also need to compile with `--with-ldap`

Comment: Hm... I don't have access to the machine now but I have a feeling that's what I needed. I mentioned above I added the php.ini directory to PATH, perhaps I was misread something saying to add the extensions directory to the PATH. I possibly copied the two .dll files straight into system32 last time I set this up, so I wouldn't have found any clues when I checked that machine's PATH

Comment: @FrankFarmer it's working now! Those two files were sitting in the same directory that `php.ini` was in but obviously weren't being found. I added that directory to the windows PATH and LDAP became enabled! I checked the first machine again (the one that was working) after that for those files, they were in PHP's default extension folder. So maybe copying them in there is all that's needed, rather than using the PATH variable. I didn't think to check at the time, but tomorrow morning I'll move those files and reboot. Then I'll post back here again just to have everything covered.

Comment: @FrankFarmer Your comment led directly to the solution, so if you'd like to post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: when I saw `php.ini` file this `(extension = php_ldap.dll)` was not there I just added this line and ldap enabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few hints here: http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php . Note you need to add two other DLLs `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`. You may also need to compile with `--with-ldap`

Answer (score 4):

I followed these instructions but still couldn't get LDAP loading in my phpinfo(). The Apache logs showed on startup the following non-fatal message: `######/php5.4.16/ext/php_ldap.dll - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0`

In the end, I looked at phpinfo() again and saw that the system variable PATH was being used instead of my user variable PATH and it didn't contain the correct path to PHP's root and PHP's extension folder. Simply adding them in `####\php\php5.4.16;####\php\php5.4.16\ext;` and restarting Apache, solved the problem. Hope this can help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out **libsasl.dll** **libeay32.dll**, **ssleay32.dll** in your PHP folder
2. If **libeay32.dll**, **ssleay32.dll** are not there, download it from https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads
3. Copy them to **System32** folder in Windows
4. Now you can see LDAP section on you **phpinfo()**. it worked for me.

**My environment**
Windows 10
PHP 7.4.3
Apache 2.4.41

Answer (score -1):

im using phpstorm. if you cant find the comment, just paste"extension = php_ldap.dll" at the bottom of your php.ini page. you are welcome