# WAMPserver 64-bit, but Windows Task Manager showing wampmanager.exe *32?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

Is it possible to be running a 64-bit version of PHP on a 32-bit version of WAMPserver?
Here's why I ask...when I go to my index.php page, it states that I am running WAMPServer version 2.4.

When I click on phpinfo it states that the Architecture is x64.

However task manager shows the process name is wampmanager.exe *32.

How can wampmanager.exe be 32-bit if php is x64?

Comment: They're two different pieces of software, one is 32, one is 64. I don't see where the confusion comes from. Windows 64 bit supports running both 32 and 64 bit software.

Comment: real world equivalent: just because you have CS degree doesn't mean that your boss with a degree in basketweaving can't manage you. A 32bit app can manage a 64bit process quite easily.

Comment: @MarcB +1 excellent example!

Comment: I guess I think it is confusing that all this software came in one "package" so-to-speak from wampserver.com, so I'd expect all to be the same bit.  Just want to make sure I understand - when I am asked if I am running 32 or 64 bit wampserver the answer is 32.  And when I am asked if I am running 32 or 64 bit php, the answer is 64.  Is that true?  Where in the in the items installed from wampserver.com, could I confirm this?  It seems odd that I'd have to go into windows task manager to confirm the version of wampserver I am running is in fact 32-bit, not 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

**WAMPServer** is an installer of software, it allows you to download Apache/MySQL/PHP in a pre-configured state so that it runs out of the box without you needing to know anything about what you are doing with Apache/MySQL or PHP. *Appropriate really in the circumstances.*

**wampmanager.exe** is part of the tool. It is in fact aestan.exe a general purpose exe that accepts commands to dynamically create a tray icon with menus, and perform actions based on clicking those menu items.

wampmanager.exe is a 32bit executable, regardless of wether you installed WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit.

WAMPServer comes in both 32bit and 64bit versions.

This in fact denotes the compiler used to compile Apache/MySQL and PHP. So if you have the 32bit WAMPServer, you have Apache/MySQL and PHP ALL COMPILED with a 32BIT compiler. If you have WAMPServer 64bit, you have Apache/MySQL and PHP ALL COMPILED with a 64BIT compiler.

Now you could mix and match as long as Apache and PHP were either BOTH 32bit or 64bit.
MySQL can be either as there is not direct interface between them. BUT I DONT ADVISE YOU TRY THAT. (KISS being best applied here)

To be honest there is no point in the 64bit WAMPServer (unless your are a real nerd ) if you are using it as it was intended i.e. a local testing environment, or even if you have foolishly used it for a live website environment, as, PHP(64bit) is not a complete port yet and as denoted on the `php.net` website, is still considered **EXPERIMENTAL**

Comment: Please excuse the sarcasm! I spend quite a bit of time helping people get familiar with WAMPServer, and the thing that always amazes me is that they expect to install 2 pieces of complex server software without making any effort to learn anything about the software they installed. After a while it starts to show as sarcasm.

Comment: Understood...but please also keep in mind that not all of us (indeed fewer and fewer of us unfortunately) seem to be afforded the luxury by our employers of "education time".  My last three jobs have been very mush one person doing the work of three.  I've been in the industry 18 years - started on Cobol back in the day, actually as Cobol was becoming a dinosaur - and I remember what it was like to have time to learn things properly.  I miss it!

Comment: Yup, old Cobol programmers never die, they just hang around in working storage. But the point still stands, you have 2 complex servers running now, if you need to do some training there is always evenings and weekends and a good old fashioned book or ebook. Remember, time is an illusion, lunchtime (and evenings ) doubly so!

Answer (score 0):

WampManager is only a 32-bit form interface for manage other service (Apache, MySQL, etc.).  WampManager "start" and "stop" a 64-bit Apache service (httpd.exe) with 64-bit PHP DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out what the issue was.  (I got so far off track in this post I didn't even mention a main problem was the Aestan tray errors and WAMP would not start properly.) In the end, these two posts - [Unable to enable PHP LDAP even though I have edited php.ini and php_ldap.dll is in the right place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826379/unable-to-enable-php-ldap-even-though-i-have-edited-php-ini-and-php-ldap-dll-is) and http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php ended up solving it.  After completely uninstalling and resinstalling WAMP (downgraded to 32-bit on RiggsFolly advice as well, just to be safe) I found that the services refused to restart after trying to enable the ldap extension via the php.ini file. I executed the steps in the stack overflow post (first link above), when that didn't work, I found the libsasl.dll file was missing from the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin directory.  I copied it there and *bam* everything started and my LDAP is working.