# How to add Apache modules to MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro

I use MAMP PRO 4.1 on macOS Sierra

I want to use the following modules in my Apache config:

- groupfile_module
- ldap_module
- authnz_ldap_module
- suexec_module
- proxy_html_module
- xml2enc_module
- log_forensic_module

But they are not available by default in the"Servers & Services"->Apache-> modules.

I tried many ways to add them, but none worked, e.g.:

- copying them manually from the other Apache modules folder on my machine and adding to the config- the result is just "Apache server cannot be started" without any output to the log

I also created an issue for the MAMP team- http://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=5811

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't specified what the "many ways" you have tried are so not sure if you've read this already but it might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826379/unable-to-enable-php-ldap-even-though-i-have-edited-php-ini-and-php-ldap-dll-is

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I updated the question to pick the main method. regarding the link- I use MAMP on Mac, so the link info is not relevant in this case.

Comment: any news here? did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: The only working solution still is just switching to use Apache itself (without MAMP) :(